# Pop function for a stack

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, mutable-reference

I wanted to implement a stack, but I am having a lot of trouble with pop. I'm trying to do it with a while let loop, but can't seem to beat the borrow checker.

```
pub struct Stack<T>{
    top: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

struct Node<T>{
    val: T,
    under: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}
```

Here's the Stack implementation and here is pop:

```
    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T>{
        if self.top.is_none(){
            return None;
        }

        let mut last_node = &mut self.top;
        while let Some(node) = last_node{
            if node.under.is_none(){
                break;
            } else{
                last_node = &mut node.under;
            }
        }
        let return_node = std::mem::replace(last_node, None);
        return Some(return_node.unwrap().val);
    }
```

Comment: With a loop, wouldn't you be popping every node? Not just the top?

Comment: @BallpointBen I was thinking that I'm not popping the node, only "scrolling" through the references until I get to the last one. I don't quite understand the ways of the borrow-checker yet

Comment: [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to move `top` completely out of `self`, take what you need from it, then stick `under` back into `self.top`.

```rust
impl<T> Stack<T> {
    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let top = self.top.take(); // take ownership of self.top
        let Some(top) = top else {
            return None
        };

        let Node { val, under } = *top; // we own top so we can move out
        self.top = under; // put the next node down back in self
        Some(val)
    }
}

fn main() {
    // 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> None
    let mut stack = Stack {
        top: Some(
            Node {
                val: 1,
                under: Some(
                    Node {
                        val: 2,
                        under: Some(
                            Node {
                                val: 3,
                                under: None,
                            }
                            .into(),
                        ),
                    }
                    .into(),
                ),
            }
            .into(),
        ),
    };
    println!("{:?}", stack.pop());
    println!("{:?}", stack.pop());
    println!("{:?}", stack.pop());
    println!("{:?}", stack.pop());
    println!("{:?}", stack.pop());
}
```

Result:

```rust
Some(1)
Some(2)
Some(3)
None
None
```